# Google Cloud Pub/Sub SDK - subscribe() takes at least 3 arguments (2 given)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-iot

The code below, to subscribe in a topic, was working some months ago.

```py
from google.cloud import pubsub

def callback(message):
    print(message.data)
    message.ack()

project_id = "my_project"
topic_name = "xxx"
subscription_name = "xxx"

subscriber = pubsub.SubscriberClient()
topic = "projects/{}/topics/{}".format(project_id, topic_name)

subscription_name = 'projects/{}/subscriptions/{}'.format(project_id, subscription_name)

subscription = subscriber.subscribe(subscription_name)
future = subscription.open(callback)

try:
    future.result()
except Exception as ex:
    subscription.close()
    raise
```

I tried to run it now and I am getting the following error message:

> File "pubsub_sub.py", line 16, in < module >
>       subscription = subscriber.subscribe(subscription_name)
>   TypeError: subscribe() takes at least 3 arguments (2 given)

As stated in the [Google-Cloud Pub/Sub](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/tree/master/pubsub) documentation, it seems my code is right. Also, as I said, this same code was working in the past. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in [the docs](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/pubsub/subscriber/index.html#subscription-callbacks), you're missing the callback.

It does look like the [README.rst](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/blob/master/pubsub/README.rst) on Github is wrong, since on [the code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/blob/master/pubsub/google/cloud/pubsub_v1/subscriber/client.py#L92) we can see those 3 arguments are required:

```
def subscribe(
        self, subscription, callback, flow_control=(),
        scheduler=None):
```

I've just proposed a [fix](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/compare/master...Jofre:patch-1) to the file for clarification.

**Edit:**

Regarding the fact that it previously worked, you can see in the repo how on pull [5237](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/commit/1acc8c22664229b6681ff91654932998e611e1c2#diff-38bec76034f4f0ee0569a0cba1d6357fR147) subscribe_experimental was created, and this method required the callback, unlike the [regular subscribe](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/commit/1acc8c22664229b6681ff91654932998e611e1c2#diff-38bec76034f4f0ee0569a0cba1d6357fL96). Later on, on pull [5274](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/commit/0da12f692070258b652d8a807a5f00c44bdbe618#diff-38bec76034f4f0ee0569a0cba1d6357fR92), subscribe_experimental was promoted to subscribe, meaning that now the callback is required.

If you're having errors when providing the callback, make sure all your libraries are up to date.

Comment: It is strange, because, as I said, this code worked some months before. Anyway, I updated it to: `subscription = subscriber.subscribe(subscription_name, callback)

try:
    subscription.result()
except Exception as ex:
    subscription.close()
    raise`. Now I am getting this message: No handlers could be found for logger "grpc._plugin_wrapping".

Comment: Added some more info on the answer to provide some context about why this is now failing.